# Compare xsl param with value in xsl if clause

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement

I am quite new to XSLT. The following template is ought to be used to concatenate colors of many products having the same item_group_id.

```
<xsl:template name="find-colors" mode="concat">
  <xsl:param name="param_item_group_id" />
  <xsl:param name="products" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$products/product">
    <xsl:if test="item_group_id = $param_item_group_id">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat($param_item_group_id,\'-\',item_group_id,\'-\', color,\', \')" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

In the calling template an item_group_id is set as $param_item_group_id. Concatenation itself works great, but I cannot seem to find a way to make

```
<xsl:if test="item_group_id = $param_item_group_id">
```

work. The statement is always true, so in the output of this template also these kinds of strings exist

```
354655-354655-green, 54655-354632-red, 354655-354632-green
```

where it is supposed to be only

```
354655-354655-green
```

Thank you,

Peter

**EDIT:**

Final solution (adapted from what JLRishe suggested) is to use

```
<xsl:if test="item_group_id[position()] = $param_item_group_id[position()]">
```

to map values of both arrays.

Comment: Could you share your input XML, and perhaps the XSL for the template that's calling this one?  Is it possible that a single `<product>` could have more than one `<item_group_id>` child node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two possible explanations for this:

1. `$param_item_group_id` contains more than one node.
2. There are `product`s with more than one `item_group_id`:

For example, if `$param_item_group_id` looked like this:

```
[1] - <someNode>54655<someNode>
[2] - <someNode>354632<someNode>
```

and you had a `product` like this:

```
<product>
   <item_group_id>354632</item_group_id>
   <name>widgets</name>
   <color>periwinkle</color>
</product>
```

The comparison would evaluate to `true` (because they have a value in common), and the `value-of` would produce `54644-354632-periwinkle` (because "54655" is the first node value in `$param_item_group_id`).  In the opposite case (one node in `$param_item_group_id` and more than one `item_group_id` in a `product`), the same thing could happen.

That's only conjecture. I'd need to see your source XML and more of the XSLT to provide a more confident answer or help you remedy the issue.

I would expect this to prevent those incongruous outputs:

```
<xsl:if test="item_group_id[1] = $param_item_group_id[1]">
```

but I suspect there is a deeper underlying issue that this would not fix.

**To clarify your questions from the comments:**

The equality operator in XPath works differently from equality in a lot of other languages. Supposing `A` or `B` or both are node-sets, the expression `A = B` will be true if *any* of the values in `A` equal *any* of the values in `B`.  Hence my description above.

Regarding this question:

> > correct me if I'm wring, but this should not display if it was an array, right?

It would display. Passing a nodeset to `concat()` converts it to a string value, and the string value of a nodeset is the string value of its first node. If the value of the first node in `$param_item_group_id` is 54644, then that is what would display.

I think that `$param_item_group_id` is exhibiting some behavior that you haven't pinned down and it's possible there's an issue in the way you're producing it.  I'd suggest trying out the following to get a closer look at the contents of this variable:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('param_item_group_id contains ', 
                             count($param_item_group_id),
                             ' nodes.')" />
<xsl:for-each select="$param_item_group_id">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ', ')" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Hi JL, thank you. My XML looks very much like your example, but every <product> has only one <item_group_id> - actually the 54644 in 54644-354632-periwinkle is the value of $param_item_group_id in the generated XML - correct me if I'm wring, but this should not display if it was an array, right? Moreover I do not understand how the if-clause could be true if "one of the values in $param_item_group_id" equals the value of item_group_id in the current <product>. Anyway I have altered code to test to item_group_id[1] = $param_item_group_id[1] and it works marvelessly. Thanks again!

Comment: @Peavey Glad to help. I've added a bit more explanation above.

Comment: thank you. I - again - forgot that XSLT is declarative and not procedural. Of course both item_group_id and $param_item_group_id are arrays. I finally solved the issue by using <xsl:if test="item_group_id[position()] = $param_item_group_id[position()]">